# why object initializer don't use the variable to access the fields or property?

Tags: c#

```
class Cat
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

I'm a beginner of C#, I want to ask an example as above.
When we initialize the field Age and property Name, Why we don't write the statement as following:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { cat.Age = 10, cat.Name = "Fluffy" };
```

Another question: when we declare a Method, why the variable could access the property directly if the class Cat hasn't executed instantiation yet, as following:

```
static void CatAge(Cat cat) 
    {
        cat.Age = 12;
    }


class Cat
{

  public int Age
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Comment: in the constructor cat is not initialized yet.

Answer (score 5):

Because `cat` hasn't been initialized yet; thus you're unable to access it. Further, even if you *could*, there's no point. You're initializing *that instance*. There's no need to specify which instance you're initializing. It would cause further confusions, because then one might expect to be able to write:

```
var firstCat = new Cat();
var secondCat = new Cat { firstCat.Age = 10 }; // ???
```

Answer (score 0):

First is answered by Rob. As for second, at the time of writing code, Cat class contains Age property, hence the editor allows accessing your property.

It will be at run time, it will try to assign 12. It will throw exception if its null, otherwise it will allow.